# Sharepoint 2010 add Note Board to Custom List

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, custom-lists

Is it possible to add a note board or other web parts to a Custom List? I would like to be able to have comments on list items.

Answer (score 1):

any particular reason you don't want to use a discussion board? That's it's entire purpose.

Comment: Do you mean use a discussion board in place of the custom list? It wouldnt serve the same purpose. A custom list contains all of the fields that I need to have for that paticular item. What I need to do is have the ability to let users comment on each item in the list.

Comment: @Jeremy you can add columns to a discussion board list type. Or you can simply add another column to your custom list called "comments" and give the users the ability to add to it. The plus side of using a discussion board is you gain all the features around discussions that someone else has already thought of, like threading. :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a data view webpart for your list. This webpart will display one item at a time, so you have to filter this dataview webpart by Item ID using querystring. The page on which you will deploy this dataview webpart will also have noteboard webpart. Comments given here will stick to that particular item which will be displayed in dataview based on Item ID.